# Interesting Property of Tri-Rectangular Tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, triangles, 3d

For starters, we know that a trirectangular tetrahedron is a tetrahedron where all three face angles at one vertex are right angles.

Here's an **interesting property** I stumbled upon, of which I look for an **elegant proof**:

(For the sake of explanation, I shall model this tetrahedron in the Cartesian plane, with origin as a vertex and the three normal vectors of the three faces intersecting at the origin, along the coordinate axes)

*And here it goes*

Consider the plane,
$$
\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1
$$
forming a tetrahedron OABC, with the XY, YZ, and ZX planes. O is the origin, and A,B,C are the other three vertices. The property is, that, the **foot of perpendicular from O, on plane ABC, is the orthocentre of triangle ABC.**

I have *already proved it*, with an analytic approach (extending the Cartesian model I describe above), however, I'm looking for a rather elegant, and possible **geometric proof** for this property.

Please share your ideas and proofs, thanks a lot!

P.S.
Feel free to ask for the analytic proof (It's probably *too obvious, and also undesirably lengthy*) which I've completed. (I shall attach a picture of the handwritten work to this post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $OABC$ be your tetrahedron. $OA$ is perpendiclular to $OB$ and $OC$, so $OA$ is perpendicular to the plane $OBC$ and, in particular, $OA \perp BC$. Now, the [theorem of three perpendiculars](https://www.math-only-math.com/theorem-of-three-perpendiculars.html) states that if some line is perpendicular to $l$, then its projection onto any plane containing $l$ is also perpendicular to $l$. So, if $H$ is the foot of perpendicular from $O$ onto $ABC$, then $AH\perp BC$.

By the way, tetrahedrons such that each pair of opposite edges are perpendicular are called [orthocentric tetrahedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_tetrahedron). Your fact is true for any orthocentric tetrahedron.